# Function names evaluated as text in legend in R?

Tags: r, function, plot

I was wondering how I could have `d` in my ***R code below*** be used in `legend`?

Note that the reason I don't use `d = c("dnorm", "dcauchy")` is that in my actual code I need to use `d[[1]](0)` which doesn't work with quotations.

```
plot(1)
d = c(dnorm, dcauchy)
legend("topleft", legend = d) ## HERE how can I have the two terms:
                              ## dnorm and dcauchy in `d` appear as legend?
```

Comment: `d = c("dnorm", "dcauchy")`   ?

Comment: @rnorouzian you need to update/clarify your question then - because what GSW provided works fine to add the above text to a legend.

Comment: @rnorouzian - i think you would be better served if you show your data and the figure code and exactly what you are trying to do. it appears like you are trying to assign values/labels  instead of simply label the figure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to use the same list as both the names and the functions you can do this.

```
d = c("dnorm", "dcauchy")     # works for printing strings
```

And when you want to use it as a function write

```
get(d[[1]])(0)
[1] 0.3989423
```

Comment: @morouzian  No apology necessary I will look at your question.